# Is there a way to get notification whenever a call get terminated

Tags: android

Is it possible to get notification whenever a call get terminated?
Is there any Intent I can register a broadcast receiver for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you may want register one of this intent's actions: [`ACTION_ANSWER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER) and/or [`ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL). Then you will have to create and register a `PhoneStateListener` and listen for `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`.

Take a look at this example: [How do I get state of a outgoing call in android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872214/how-do-i-get-state-of-a-outgoing-call-in-android-phone/3608415#3608415)