# How to know that the dialled number has received a ring?

Tags: android

My app requires to know whether the other party has recived my call or not. I need to execute some logic after 1 or 2 rings.

To do this I have overridden onCallStateChanged method, and check for CALL_STATE_RINGING state. But it looks like this method is not 100% perfect since it takes some time for the ring to happen after the state changes to CALL_STATE_RINGING.

Any suggestions on how to go ahead with the implementation? One approach is to have some delay of 2 to 3 seconds after the state changes to CALL_STATE_RINGING. But this approach is really dumb since the delay will vary between telcos. Any other ideas?

Comment: For some reason CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK is showing up 3 times when I make a call

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is possible to detect when the other party picked up, still i think this link can be useful to you

[How do I get state of a outgoing call in android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872214/how-do-i-get-state-of-a-outgoing-call-in-android-phone)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Really wonder why Google did not provide enums to find out the state of the outgoing call. Obviously the handset will know the state of the outgoing call from Vendor RIL (unsolicited response from baseband). This just needs to be communicated to framework like the other state change responses.