# Phonegap / Android - Phone call recognition

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, interrupt

I want to make an app, that looks, at the moment of an incoming phone call, into the database for the related number.

So I wanted to ask, if there is a possibility to get some kind of **interrupt or event**, that tells my program in the background, that there is an **incoming phone call**?

I am seeking solutions for android and cordova 
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872214/how-do-i-get-state-of-a-outgoing-call-in-android-phone or http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html, They're both ways to implement this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any plugins implementing that kind of feature yet. But implementing it by yourself shouldn't be too hard since the Java code is available on [Gabe Sechan's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/1744702).

Also there is the [PhoneCall Trap plugin](https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap) that offers you a scaffold to build the plugin on as it already catches the event of incoming call.